# Subtract strings from columns and keep original index in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, selection

I have a df containing two columns:

```
country      amount
USA          34 
USA          21
China        5
France       7
Italy        9
USA          1
Spain        10
Ireland      12
```

I wanted to create 3 variables based on continents: USA, China and Europe for further calculation with the 'amount' column.

For USA and China I did like this:

```
    usa = df.loc[df['country']=='USA']['country']
    china = df.loc[df['country']=='China (Mainland)']['country']
```

For Europe I got stuck because I would need all the European countries in the column and maintaining its index (so the respective amounts).

Is it possible to subtract from ['country'] usa and china, to get the rest (European countries) and store them in a variable 'europe'?

The end goal is to get, for example, the sum of amounts of all European countries, and unfortunately there isn't another 'marker' to distinguish them as European.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the Country's that not are `USA` or `China`.

To do this, you can use the following

```
europe = df.loc[(df['country']!='China (Mainland)') & (df['country']!='USA')]['country']
```

Answer (score 1):

Check with

```
EU = df.loc[~df['country'].isin(['USA', 'China (Mainland)'])]['country']
```

Comment: what is for the ~ in ~df['country'] ? Thanks

Comment: @Steven in to not in ~

Answer (score 0):

> USA and China are not continents :)

```
df['continent'] = 'Europe'
df['continent'][df['country']=='USA'] = 'USA'
df['continent'][df['country']=='China'] = 'China (Mainland)'
```